# Trying to INSERT NULL if input field left blank now it shows 0

Tags: php, html, mysql

When I send an empty field from my form, it shows 0 on the page.

How can I hide or delete the 0 and just show nothing?

Because now there are 0's everywhere on my page. I don't need to show it if it's empty, I only need it when there is something to show.

Can someone tell me what to do please?

Here's the code of `page.php`:

```
<?php 
    require_once 'db_config.php';
    $ID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Titaan']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Buit WHERE Titaan_ID = '$ID' ";

    if(!$res = mysql_query($sql))
    {
        trigger_error(mysql_error().'<br />In query: '.$sql);
    }
    elseif(mysql_num_rows($res) == 0)
    {
        echo 'Geen resultaten gevonden';
    }
    else
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
            echo '<tr><td>'. $row['Titaan'].'</td> ';
            echo '<td bgcolor="'. $row['Kleur']. '">'. $row['Kleur'].' </td> ';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Sterren'].' </td> ';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Status'].' </td> ';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Rank'].' </td> ';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Buit_Niveau'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Damage'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Level'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot1'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot1_value'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot2'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot2_value'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot3'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot3_value'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot4'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot4_value'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot5'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot5_value'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot6'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot6_value'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot7'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot7_value'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot8'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot8_value'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot9'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot9_value'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot10'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot10_value'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot11'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot11_value'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot12'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['Loot12_value'].'</td></tr>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Here's the code to send form to MySQL, `send.php`

```
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$result = $_POST['Titaan'];
$result_explode = explode('|', $result); 
$Split1 = $result_explode[0];
$Split2 = $result_explode[1];
$Split3 = $result_explode[2];

// Escape user inputs for security
$ID =           mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['ID']);
$Titaan_ID =    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Split1);
$Titaan =       mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Split2);
$Kleur =        mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Split3);
$Sterren =      mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Sterren']);
$Status =       mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Status']);
$Rank =         mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Rank']);
$Buit_Niveau =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Buit_Niveau']);
$Damage =       mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Damage']);
$Level =        mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Level']);
$Loot1 =        mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot1']);
$Loot1_value =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot1_value']);
$Loot2 =        mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot2']);
$Loot2_value =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot2_value']);
$Loot3 =        mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot3']);
$Loot3_value =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot3_value']);
$Loot4 =        mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot4']);
$Loot4_value =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot4_value']);
$Loot5 =        mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot5']);
$Loot5_value =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot5_value']);
$Loot6 =        mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot6']);
$Loot6_value =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot6_value']);
$Loot7 =        mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot7']);
$Loot7_value =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot7_value']);
$Loot8 =        mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot8']);
$Loot8_value =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot8_value']);
$Loot9 =        mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot9']);
$Loot9_value =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot9_value']);
$Loot10 =       mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot10']);
$Loot10_value = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot10_value']);
$Loot11 =       mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot11']);
$Loot11_value = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot11_value']);
$Loot12 =       mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot11']);
$Loot12_value = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['Loot11_value']);

// attempt insert query execution

$sql = "INSERT INTO Buit (ID, Titaan_ID, Titaan, Kleur, Sterren, Status, Rank, Buit_Niveau, Damage, Level, Loot1, Loot1_value, Loot2, Loot2_value, Loot3, Loot3_value, Loot4, Loot4_value, Loot5, Loot5_value, Loot6, Loot6_value, Loot7, Loot7_value, Loot8, Loot8_value, Loot9, Loot9_value, Loot10, Loot10_value, Loot11, Loot11_value, Loot12, Loot12_value) VALUES ('$ID', '$Titaan_ID', '$Titaan', '$Kleur', '$Sterren', '$Status', '$Rank', '$Buit_Niveau', '$Damage', '$Level', '$Loot1','$Loot1_value', '$Loot2','$Loot2_value', '$Loot3','$Loot3_value', '$Loot4','$Loot4_value', '$Loot5','$Loot5_value', '$Loot6','$Loot6_value', '$Loot7','$Loot7_value', '$Loot8','$Loot8_value', '$Loot9','$Loot9_value', '$Loot10','$Loot10_value', '$Loot11','$Loot11_value', '$Loot12','$Loot12_value')";
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: A schema like this is also a flagrant violation of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). A proper relational structure is considerably easier to work with and is not limited to any arbitrary number of items. Don't treat your SQL database like a fancy spreadsheet. It's meant to be used differently.

Comment: You also *urgently* need to learn how to use loops more effectively as there's rampant duplication of code here that's bound to introduce tiny, but obnoxious bugs due to a simple typographical error.

Comment: why are you use the mysql_ api in one piece of code, then switching over to mysqli_?

Comment: thanks for comment but no idea where you talking about :shame: im total noob with coding ect its just for fun im trying it and it works fine for with how it is now the only thing is the "0" prob

Comment: so im no pro coder im just trying things and google something need/ what work :P

Comment: @Fred-ii- because these codes are of google and from different scripts i just copied the codes that i needed / worked for me and combined them to the thing you see :P so if i see the comment i think it works but its a total crap :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People already said you should use `mysqli` or `PDO` to interface php with the MySQL server.
By the way, `NULL` values returned by MySQL are `null` references in php, the `===` operator should help you:

```
if ($row["col"] === null) {
   // the value in the db is NULL!
} else {
   // go ahead with the non-NULL value.
}
```

I’m pretty sure it works with `mysqli`, not so sure for the obsolete `mysql_*` function bundle.

**Note: ** probably it’s `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to treat `null` values as `0` integers, and they’re creating a `"0"` but it’s just a thought of mine.